# What happened on September 24 1990 (or 1998) at 08:24?

Tags: gaming-history, mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

I’ve just bought Mario + Rabbids Kingdom Battle. It’s a great game! Played through the first world already.

There are retro pop culture references all over it!

Anyway, in the opening scene there is a time machine built out of a washing machine. It has a display very reminiscent of the DeLorean in BTTF. It even has a flux capacitor in the drum and the display reads “888”.

[image]

So, I got interested and started to look closely at it.

The three dates are...

1. Sept 23 1889 11:27
2. March 12 1986 23:59
3. Sept 24 1990 08:24 (on closer inspection it could be 1998)

I found the first two dates.

1. Is the date that the company Nintendo was founded.
2. Is the date that the company Ubisoft was founded.
3. Is ...

I can’t seem to find it. The closest I’ve found so far is that the SNES was released in December 1990 but that can’t be right.

So... what is it referring to? I find this stuff fascinating :-)

**Edit**

I think the third year might be 1998. It’s hard to tell because it uses a digital display that’s sort of fuzzy.

Comment: What if it isn't a video game reference? Are there any real world dates possibly relating to this from a time travel perspective? Just a thought.

Comment: @Typhon I thought about that but I can’t really find anything on any “on this day” websites or anything.

Comment: @Fogmeister alrighty. I've never played the game either so I wouldn't rule out it having an in-game importance as well. Based on it appearing like a log of previous points of travel it *might* be when that inventor was at the beginning of the game with the merging machine with the other two being (joke) locations of other places the Rabbids went to.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Watching [one video](https://youtu.be/7wjgcXBuSKM?t=3m36s) on the game discussing this, they believe that this was the day the Ubisoft Milan was founded, who helped to develop this game.  However, they weren't able to track down an exact date of when Ubisoft Milan was first founded.  The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubisoft_Milan) only states 1998.

There is also a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/6xln3t/first_date_is_foundation_of_nintendo_second_is_of/) discussing this as well, and the Milan studio was also mentioned, as well as a game called Anno 1602, which was made by a company that Ubisoft acquired in 2007, and apparently published on this date.  As suggested in the comments, it's possible some of the developers from this studio worked on this game.

Without officially knowing, I would say that this was the date that Ubisoft Milan was founded.  Considering the second date seems to be about Ubisoft as well, I think that this is pretty likely.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether that 1998 date is correct for the founding of Ubisoft Milan, as [the oldest annual report](https://ubistatic19-a.akamaihd.net/comsite_common/en-US/images/Annual_Report_2001_tcm99-27525_tcm99-196733-32.pdf) I can find from them (admittedly only goes back to 2001 on their website) describes "*new design and production facilities in New York, Barcelona, **Milan** and Tokyo*" as happening in 1999-2000 (see page 28, first column).

Comment: Actually, Anno 1602 was not made by Ubisoft at all. It was developed by Max Design (Austria) and published by Sunflowers (Germany). Sunflowers was bought by Ubisoft in 2007, 9 years after Anno 1602. It might still be possible, that former Sunflowers members were actively working on the Mario title though, making this connection reasonable.